# Which encryption method has been used?

Tags: decompilation, decryption

Anyone please can you tell me which method used to encrypt this kind of codes?

im really confused, that would really helps me.

This encrypted data created by a PHP.

> Ibª„bÏ}◊Kì-yNî˜>Eﬁ¶ØÁÇ_^§    Ùa¥ròÒ1å°R*ÑØÑ∆«œ
> ÿ¡t“≤=Fz#"Ô]7V´aY+ªæ'Ë]Yÿ!®¢cj˝ﬂ√¿*>ÒŸﬁ!A*3¨§†–k © ÷Bävè1Ù
> ‚L2lra%F ı˚≈‰ÅºóΩ0ª⁄W›>kü≈D#ìÀ
> w-¢eLìí+-„eï‘r∫ê:…ôæù¬SèW¸§W»z¢ΩVΩ/√/hüt|KQÓËﬁ—7}ßJ#âù˚ÿãá"ÙÎ†Öi§@c’QSµÍA˙ùı9“„øgX ıs´M®w!Â;<›´Ú›í:f[‰)p5L@⁄
> «],ÀYÅÀæø¿ÃﬁüZG~√á.≈ÛÚ±¶„N˘äô.2-òÂmΩEm‡4o/Â2tOCl≤mäÕM˘2ì¸ef{´¸:…)v!E"~ævìå    Ôrc∂Ã4!ï6¥≈∏®pZ3-¥„æ·cCÀ¬cYÜà›Lmù∞ùπNa˘´tÿPΩ”∫yï«÷3OQ3ÊÓÌã∂Á∞paÔÓ‹Hœ…˚ÂÈbr?•>°’À¥v*K&µH'p,oÔÛ(ªßAOg>5áÜÅ∑ì˘Ò¸›˘%    ‰¸πÆÀùŒ¯ôüß¨üÛƒ¥.X.wèÁU„≠|æƒÃÄ<ë∫õ ôÛjjM)™mı”“WoRZáôÚÛXi2   ÿ
> |pÏq`ùm≥‡º€[˜¯„c-ÙUD¸º˛ç“3≤Hó÷ŸnÈ
> ”˝¯c¸˛ÃÍ#ﬂKéjÛXﬂ*%v‰jB>±\V«õœøOo≤/Z®PèL∂K¬´øP€Q∑‹ﬁ¨#yÔàJ/˝ñã3∞ÆùÅ©2Ü>¸    ê≈”4ﬁß„˚6ÿúúµ‡lÑ;¥'G"˜Sæ_ƒ|\ÚN
> Fí2~%tI°ëíX¶ÄHnwß,[åöp'j«…e|)ÂG_H=75´P¶≈ıìè∫k¡€6Ó

When i run the file it's automatically add the file /usr/local/haxor

Here is the code of PHP that sending Post request.

```
        $interface = exec('route | grep \'^default\' | grep -o \'[^ ]*$\'');
                $interface = str_replace("\n", '', $interface);
                $mac = file_get_contents('/sys/class/net/' . $interface . '/address');
                $mac = str_replace("\n", '', $mac);
                $hostname = exec('hostname');
                $hostname = str_replace("\n", '', $hostname);
                $k = exec('uname -r');
                $k = str_replace("\n", '', $k);
                $inode = fileinode('/usr/bin/haxor');
                $currentversion = file_get_contents('/usr/local/haxor/version');
                $currentversion = str_replace("\n", '', $currentversion);
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.othoy.com/key.php');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'interface=' . $interface . '&mac=' . $mac . '&inode=' . $inode . '&hostname=' . $hostname . '&k=' . $k . '&version=' . $currentversion . '');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
                $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                if (file_exists('/usr/local/haxor')) {
                    file_put_contents('/usr/local/haxor', $server_output);
                }
```

Comment: It looks like `https://www.othoy.com/key.php` is driving the encryption, do you have a copy of it?

Comment: @MegaTonnage sorry i dont have it, i just wanted to know what kind of data is encrypted there or which method used to encrypt it.